# TypeScript: weird function overloads bug when the overload is implemented via interface instead of multiple function declarations

Tags: typescript

I think I've run into a bug in TypeScript's function overload resolution.

Here I implement a function overload using multiple function declarations

```js
function func(n: number): void;
function func(prefix: string, n: number): void;
function func(first: string | number, n?: number): void {
}
```

Then I defined an interface for the same overload

```js
interface Func {
    (n: number): void;
    (prefix: string,  n: number): void;
}
```

let's do an assignment to see if the type is correct

```js
const fn: Func = func // ✅ no issues!
```

but as soon as I create a new function of `Func` type, things get weird

```js
const fn2: Func = (a, b) => {} // ❌ type '(a: string, b: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'Func'.
```

I cannot figure out why there is a type error - it seems to me that `a` should be typed as `string | number` and `b` should be an optional `number`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33482 are relevant; I doubt the TS team considers this a bug.  I'll keep looking when I get a chance

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think this is bug-like or a limitation; if you [explicitly annotate the parameters](https://tsplay.dev/WoDzjw) everything works.  So the issue is with contextual typing.  It seems like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42620 should have maybe given this a good contextual type (as of TS4.3) but it doesn't seem to synthesize an optional parameter this way.  I will keep looking.

Comment: Added [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42620#issuecomment-1037684948), maybe I'll open a new GitHub issue about it.

Comment: @jcalz thanks! was wondering if you could maybe give me a brief description of the bug or limitation you are seeing here?

Comment: I might wait to write up an answer until I get some word from people on GitHub, but the basic situation is that as of TypeScript 4.3, the compiler makes a single [contextual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) call signature for overloads; if you implement an overloaded function with a callback and don't annotate the parameters, the compiler will infer them for you. If you write `const f: Func = a => {}` it will work fine and infer that `a` is of type `string | number`. But the second parameter in `(a, b) => {}` confuses it.

Comment: @jcalz thanks. the function overload feature in typescript seems to have some weirdness. Is it true that function overload feature were introduced long before we have union and intersection types and a lot of use cases it served now can be served using union types? Do you have any good resources on learning how to use  this feature effectively?